# Rotating View in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to make a little Ember View widget that rotates the template every 3 seconds. This is far as I have gotten, but it doesn't seem to be working correctly. Am I going with the right approach or can anyone suggest how to do this?

**UPDATED:**

This almost works, but it doesn't cycle through the templates correctly as it is updating far too frequently. Here's [a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mehulkar/L35gA/). (WARNING, Fiddle becomes unresponsive eventually because it gets overloaded with updates to the DOM)

```coffee
App.RotatingView = Ember.View.extend
  templateString: null
  views: ["a", "b", "c"]

  init: ->
    @set 'templateString', @_getNextTemplate()
    @_super()

  template: (->
    Ember.Handlebars.compile(@get 'templateString')
  ).property('templateString')

  templateDidChange: (->
    setInterval =>
      @set 'templateString', @_getNextTemplate()
      Ember.run.next => @rerender()
    , 3000
  ).observes("templateString")

  _getNextTemplate: ->
    views = @get('views')
    length = views.length

    currentTemplateIndex = views.indexOf this.get('templateString')

    if (currentTemplateIndex + 1) == length
      return views[0]
    else
      return views[currentTemplateIndex + 1]
```

**UPDATE #2**

I also attempted the `ContainerView` approach suggested by @Unspecified below, but I get 'Cannot call methods 'childViewsDidChange' of undefined.

```coffee
App.RotatingView = Ember.ContainerView.extend
  views: Em.A(["a", "b", "c"])

  childViews: (->
    views = @get('views')
    return views.map (view) -> Ember.View.create({template: Ember.Handlebars.compile(view)})
  ).property('views.@each')

  init: ->
    @set 'currentView', @get('childViews.firstObject')
    @_super()

  viewDidChange: (->
    setInterval =>
      @set 'currentView', @_getNextView()
    , 3000
  ).observes('currentView')

  _getNextView: ->
    views = @get('childViews')
    length = views.length

    currentTemplateIndex = views.indexOf this.get('templateString')

    if (currentTemplateIndex + 1) == length
      return views[0]
    else
      return views[currentTemplateIndex + 1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a problem with your templateDidChange method: since it `observes('templateString')`, it will be run every time that templateString changes, and so you'll end up with an awful lot of setInterval calls (I think that's the reason [your latest fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mehulkar/L35gA/) bogs down).

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/FARwf/2/)'s a fiddle that seems to work as you expect - I simply moved the setInterval into the `init` method.

Comment: Also, if you're wanting to go down the ContainerView route (it'd probably a more elegant, at least) - check out "Binding a View to Display" at http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ContainerView.html

Comment: An example with the container view as a bonus ?

Comment: I'll work on one now - Unspecified's third example should work nicely, though I'm running into issues at the moment.

Comment: I think you can just update the 'currentView' property of the container view.

Comment: Yup - that's what I was going for exactly.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**
The problem with your approach is that you made `template` computed property with no dependencies, so it gets calculated only once when it was called at the beginning, it wont get recalculated because it is not dependent on any thing

There are a lot of ways to accomplish this(Skipping the `rotations` & `_randomTemplate` from the answer)

**1.**

```
App.RotatingView = Ember.View.extend

  template: (->
    Ember.Handlebars.compile(@get('templateString'))
  ).property('templateString') 

  setInterval (->
    @set 'templateString', @_randomTemplate()
  , 3000)

  templateDidChange: (->
    @rerender()
  ).observes('template')
```

**2.**

```
App.RotatingView = Ember.View.extend

  template: (->
    string = @_randomTemplate()
    Ember.Handlebars.compile(string)
  ).property()

  setInterval: (->
    @set 'template', Ember.Handlebars.compile(@_randomTemplate)
    @rerender()
  , 3000)
```

**3.** (Using `Ember.ContainerView` , don't need `rerender` in this approach)

```
App.RotatingView = Ember.ContainerView.extend

  currentView: (->
    Ember.View.create({template: Ember.Handlebars.compile(@get('templateString'))})
  ).property('templateString')

  setInterval: (->
    @set 'templateString', @_randomTemplate
  , 3000)
```

Comment: I was expecting that the `rerender` in my `template` property would recursively call itself. None of your solutions worked exactly because of your `setInterval`. Is that supposed to be a property or an observer? What is is observing?

Comment: setInterval is a javascript method which executes a given function for every n milliseconds there must be some problems with this context, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval

Comment: I know what `setInterval` is, but it is not being called anywhere in your example. I tried this, but it is not firing either http://pastie.org/7970497

Comment: Would it be possible for you to make a fiddle with your solutions?

Comment: Well, sheldonnbbaker answered it before I could update the fiddle with the answer, hence the solution is you can use any of the three methods defined in my answer but the trick is putting the setInterval inside the init function instead of defining it as a property which I did